# How to debug 406 not acceptable error in java application using spring

Tags: java

My code is using spring boot and java but while testing a method it is showing 406 not acceptable error how to debug??

Comment: show your implemented code

Comment: have you tried using your IDE's debug facility? Perhaps you are not calling the API as designed?

Answer (score 0):

> 406 Not Acceptable
>
> The resource identified by the request is only capable of generating
> response entities which have content characteristics not acceptable
> according to the accept headers sent in the request.

So, probably your request accept header is different then your controller's produce type (application/json, text/json etc). This happens when the correct HTTPMessageConverter can not be found to satisfy the @ResponseBody annotated return value.

Please provide your controller you are testing and test case